How can I remove the wp_autop filter from a shortcode block in a block theme page template (twenty twenty-three)?
I am using a custom page template in the "twenty twenty-three" theme. I am using a shortcode block as part of the template. This results in the shortcode not running within "the_content", as that block is being called separately. I can run this specific shortcode inside the content area and in the footer (neither of which is where I want the shortcode's output to display) and it works fine. However, when I run it as a block in the page template, paragraph elements are being inserted that break the output.
I have tried applying the shortcode_unautop() function to the shortcode's output without success, and I have tried removing and then re-applying the wp_autop() filter as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940854/disable-automatic-formatting-inside-wordpress-shortcodes ... but none of it works because those seem to still need to be run within hooked areas like "the_content".  Can anyone point me toward a method of disabling wp_autop on a shortcode block within a block-theme page template?
